# How can I troubleshoot a 504 timeout error using Magento, Apache, PHP-FPM, and Varnish?

Tags: php, apache, magento2, fastcgi, http-status-code-504

I have a Magento website and am trying to start a backend process in the admin panel (in my browser) that, when submitted, warns you that the process "can take a long time". Whenever I hit submit though, I end up with a 504 timeout error and can't figure out why.

I've increased my PHP `max_execution_time` to 1800 seconds, but the request times out after exactly 60 seconds. I am using Cloudflare as a proxy, however even when I turn the proxy setting off, I still get a timeout after 60 seconds. The server is a Cloud Compute type on Vultr. Due to ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858749/5749974)) I've also checked and made sure there aren't any load balancers behind this.

I've tried checking the php-fpm and apache logs but can't find anything relevant to a 504.

How can I begin to troubleshoot this and allow the process to run as long as it needs?

Comment: Cloudflare has a hard-set timeout that you cannot change, no matter what you change on your server, though I believe it's 100 seconds on their end. The only way to get around it is to bypass Cloudflare, such as with a subdomain.

Comment: Even if I switch off the "Proxy" setting for the subdomain? It's a "dev" subdomain and I've switched off the "Proxy" toggle in Cloudflare.

Comment: There is also the [Timeout directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742580/504-gateway-time-out-the-server-didnt-respond-in-time-how-to-fix-it) in Apache

Comment: The "Proxy Status" for the dev subdomain is set to "DNS Only". I also have set the Timeout directive in httpd.conf to `18000` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up figuring this out. It turns out that a load balancer called HAProxy was bound to listen on port 443 for SSL and this had its own configuration options, specifically `Timeout Server` as described [here](https://www.papertrail.com/solution/tips/haproxy-logging-how-to-tune-timeouts-for-performance/). I found this with `netstat -ltnp` and with the help of [this other question that I asked](https://serverfault.com/a/1090657/948404). After I increased this option and restarted the service, the operation worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make changes in `.user.ini` and `.htaccess` files. Search for `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time`